# Calculating upper bound of trinomial coefficient

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to calculate the upper bound of the following term. I am not sure what approach to take.[image]

Initially I was trying to find the time complexity by breaking the above term into the following:
[image]

I think it is getting very complicated with this technique and I am not sure if this is the correct approach to proceed with.

Comment: [https://math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: You seem to be looking for the values given in https://oeis.org/A002426 (1, 3, 7, 19, 51, 141, 393...). Several efficient programs are given. If not, can you better explain.